# Python/Selenium - how to toggle java tree menu?

Tags: python, selenium

Im using selenium to pull some data from a java driven website, im having difficulty getting the data for some objects that are not expanded in the java tree. if the items are not expanded no data is shown.

this is the source for an expanded and unexpanded item (the first item is expanded) and below a image of the data expanded or collapsed

ive tried using path to get attributes but it only gets one, I then searched through the code to find something different between expanded or none expanded and I cannot see anything nor how I would click the + symbol programmatically.

in summary any item that is not expanded needs expanding so I can pull the data, if it is collapsed the page does not show data, can anyone help?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@title, "(6 Sensors)")]')
```

[image: expanded or collpased]

```
<div class="slick-row  odd" row="11" style="height:29px">
    <row>
        <div class="slick-cell lr c0 treeColumn children00">
            <div class="treeItem deviceItem cell-inner device expanded isnotfavorite remoteprobe isnotpaused" idx="11"
                level="2" objid="14305" type="device" path="0-7262-12686-14305" template="_Prtg.Core.device.js">
                <level last="true"></level>
                <level lastx="false">
                    <level>
                        <toggler></toggler>
                    </level>
                </level>
                <div class="indent level2" title="EE100743 RS&lt;br/&gt;(6 Sensors)&lt;br/&gt;OK">
                    <level class="device">
                        <icon popup="333" style="background-image:url(/icons/devices/vendors_Cradlepoint.png)"></icon>
                    </level>
                    <device>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">EE100743 RS</name>
                        <condition></condition>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" id="fav-14305" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14305,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                        <status></status>
                    </device>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-cell lr c1 valueColumn children00">
            <div class="sensorItem cell-inner c1 drop device expanded isnotfavorite remoteprobe isnotpaused" idx="11"
                objid="14305" type="device" path="0-7262-12686-14305" template="_Prtg.Core.sensor.js">
                <div>
                    <sensor idx="0" objid="14306" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="Throughput (1,25 kbit/s)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">Throughput</name>
                        <value goto="true">1,25 kbit/s</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14306,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor idx="1" objid="14307" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="Uptime (44 d)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">Uptime</name>
                        <value goto="true">44 d</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14307,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor idx="2" objid="14308" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="4G Signal strength (-103 #)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">4G Signal strength</name>
                        <value goto="true">-103 #</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14308,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor idx="3" objid="14309" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="4G Signal quality (-14 #)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">4G Signal quality</name>
                        <value goto="true">-14 #</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14309,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor idx="4" objid="14310" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="3G Signal quality (0 #)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">3G Signal quality</name>
                        <value goto="true">0 #</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14310,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor idx="5" objid="14311" type="sensor" class="sensor dragable  isnotpaused isnotfavorite status3"
                        title="Network Bearer (140 msec)">
                        <icon popup="333" goto="true"></icon>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">Network Bearer</name>
                        <value goto="true">140 msec</value>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14311,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                    </sensor>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </row>
</div>
<div class="slick-row  even" row="12" style="height:29px">
    <row>
        <div class="slick-cell lr c0 treeColumn children00">
            <div class="treeItem deviceItem cell-inner device expanded isnotfavorite remoteprobe isnotpaused" idx="12"
                level="2" objid="14298" type="device" path="0-7262-12686-14298" template="_Prtg.Core.device.js">
                <level last="true"></level>
                <level lastx="false">
                    <level>
                        <toggler></toggler>
                    </level>
                </level>
                <div class="indent level2" title="EE100843 RS&lt;br/&gt;(6 Sensors)&lt;br/&gt;OK">
                    <level class="device">
                        <icon popup="333" style="background-image:url(/icons/devices/vendors_Cradlepoint.png)"></icon>
                    </level>
                    <device>
                        <name popup="3333" goto="true">EE100843 RS</name>
                        <condition></condition>
                        <favorit>
                            <span class="objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag" id="fav-14298" onclick="_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,14298,'toggle');return false;"></span>
                        </favorit>
                        <status></status>
                    </device>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-cell lr c1 valueColumn children00">
            <div class="sensorItem cell-inner c1 drop device expanded isnotfavorite remoteprobe isnotpaused" idx="12"
                objid="14298" type="device" path="0-7262-12686-14298" template="_Prtg.Core.sensor.js">
                <div>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                    <sensor class="status3">
                        <icon></icon>
                    </sensor>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </row>
</div>
```

Comment: On your current XPath, does it only expand the first one? If so, you could change your method to `find_elements` and iterate that way

Comment: I havent got it to expand any yet, I think my method is wrong. the html of this webpage is a nightmare to navigate, I cant even find the toggle button to try click it, its all java...

Comment: bummer.. looks like data is sensitive (judging by the red rectangle you drew) so hands-on approach might not be possible from my end :-(

Comment: the source code I posted excludes the sensitive data. basically its a PRTG page, and im just expanding sensors, you'll be able to see PRTG demos online somewhere I think

Comment: Ah thanks. It appears to be the `<toggler>` elements. For me ots

Comment: yeah thats what I thought, but how would I know which ones are toggled on or off? I couldn't see that, and then how do I click only the ones which are off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Assuming all of these are devices (as shown for me):

```
all_expanded = False
while not all_expanded:
   devices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('deviceItem')
   for device in devices:
       if "collapsed" in device.get_attribute('class'):
          device.find_element_by_tag_name('toggler').click()
          all_expanded = False
          break
       else:
          all_expanded = True
```

This expands of the devices which aren't expanded already. But basically, the element to toggle this is the `<toggler>` elements. You can tell if something is expanded or not if the WebElement has the class `expanded` or `collapsed`.

EDIT: Revised the above to a `while` loop since each click manipulates the DOM (leading to the stale element error) and you'd have to re-grab the devices.

Comment: So I'll have to revise the `for` loop, each time you click the element, it manipulates the DOM and Selenium raises a `stale element` error. i'll have to figure out a more working approach!